# How to give permission to menus in Sharepoint after branding

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-branding

I have performed branding in one of my sharepoint 2013 site.
Below are the steps I foloowed
1. Created a HTML file.
2. Converted it to master page using Design Manager.

So what i need is, I have two menus in that html file say "Code Sample","Documents".

After converting it to masterpage, I want to give permission to this menu.
ie. When person A login to the site, only "Code Sample" should available.
    When person B login to the site, only "Documents" should available.

Answer (score 0):

You can show/hide components of the page based on masks ([SPBasePermissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms412690))

In the Snippet Gallery of the Design Manager, you can find the Security Trim (SPSecurityTrimmedControl):

> To display content only to those users who have a specified level of
>   security permissions, you can use a Security Trim Control. Specify one
>   or more permission levels in the Behavior section of this control's
>   properties. You can set it to many common permission levels, including
>   the option to show content to no one but contributing site authors or
>   site administrators. Then, insert the component on your page and place
>   any content - including other SharePoint components - inside of it.

Here and example:

```
<div data-name="SecurityTrimmedAdministrators">
    <!--CS: Start Security Trim Snippet-->
    <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="FullMask ">-->
        <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><span><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
        <div class="DefaultContentBlock" style="border:medium black solid; background:yellow; color:black; margin:20px; padding:10px;">
        You should replace this div with content that renders based on your Security Trim Properties.

        </div>
        <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--></span><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>-->
    <!--CE: End Security Trim Snippet-->
</div>
```

So, you can change the `Permissions` property of the `SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl` with other [masks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms412690) like EmptyMask, ViewListItems...